# Canvas LMS open tools in a new tab

Tags: iframe, tabs

I am developing a LTI tool for Canvas LMS. The tool has 2 parts, content selector and content page. The content selector is embeddable while the content page is not embeddable. When the app is launched for first time, I would like to have the content selector embedded in an iframe. After users selected certain content, the app is launched for second time, the content page will be displayed in a new tab.

For now, the content selector will be displayed in the iframe, but when it try to display content page to the user, it display nothing, and I can see the error in chrome console: refused to display in iframe because it set X-Frame-Options=DENY.

I know there is options when creating an assignment: always open the tool in a new browser window, but could I just programmatically determine when to open the tool in the iframe, when to open it in a new browser window ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas LMS (or any LMS) doesn't allow this configuration to be made on the fly. It has to be set before when you create external tool.